# Apple Push Notification Provider in own application

Tags: iphone, notifications, push, apple-push-notifications

I have some questions about apns in my own server-side application. I have a java application who should be able to send push notifications to apple. 
The server and also the iphone app is working, my question aims to the distribution of the server application and the certificates. 
Can I distribute all servers to the users with the same certificate? Or do I have to send every user their own certificate for their server?
Every server should be able to send their push messages to the apple servers for delivery, like:

Server-Application <--> Apple Push Notification Server <--> iPhone / iPad etc...

Is that possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Every server should be configure with certificate and should have SEND notification LOGIC coded in JAVA or any other language like PHP or C#.

You need one Certificate for every Server.

Every server should be preconfigure for APNS requirements. You need to build server with certificate and port enabled on that. Please check Ray wander linch' guide for APNS and you will find what it takes to do above.

Comment: So do I have to create a certificate for every server? Or can I use ONE certificate for every server? The programmaticaly things will be done with Javapns...

Comment: Okay can anybody say to me, how I create these individual certificates and how I can distribute them to the server? Do I have to do that in the provisioning portal for every sold server?

Comment: We want to sold a server application (basen on java) and the server(s) should be able to send push notifications to iOS devices.

Comment: Well in that case every server should be preconfigure for APNS requirements. You need to build server with certificate and port enabled on that. Please check Ray wander linch' guide for APNS and you will find what it takes to do above.

Comment: Ok thats clear ... but can I sell the software including the apns-provider stuff and having all the same certificates for that? Or do I have to create for every sold server a new certificate?

Comment: well ecs you can prebuild every server with Certificate and distribute the servers